# Mysterious device connected to my lan

Tags: networking, router, lan, openwrt, wired-networking

I have a dlink router with openwrt installed on it. I have noticed that a device is connected to my lan connection, and i have no idea what is it! It has no hostname, its mac address is : F8:75:A4:22:B9:9C, that is a mac address from LCFC (HeFei) Electronics Technology. Here is a list of devices connected :

- My laptop
- My proxmox server
- My windows vm
- 4 smart home devices
- My phone
- My nintendo switch

All of these devices have got a hostname that i set. I cant disconnect the mysterious device, because it is connected via wired lan.

Here is a screenshot :
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcKk4.jpg)

Is this dangerous? Should i be worried? And how could i identify this device?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT : i just had to restart the router, thats it

Comment: Which of those devices has an ip address of 10.10.10.17?

Comment: Does openwrt show you _which LAN port_ the device is connected to? (Can you run e.g. the `bridge fdb` command?)

Comment: @Ramhound the device in question has the ip : 10.10.10.117

Comment: @user1686 that command doesnt exist

Comment: Does it have `brctl showmacs` then?

Comment: So I am asking. Which of your devices in the list you provided as that address? You can eliminate most of those easily. My educated guess is that it's assigned to the VM, if the laptop is an Lenovo device, then my guess changes. You don't have to provide us any device connected to the wireless adapter, if you have evidence, the unknown device is connected to the LAN adapter.

Comment: A user with a similar question reported "Edit: turns out to be a lenovo thinkpad laptop that was disconnected from the router, I hibernated the laptop then unplugged the ethernet cable few hours ago, however it still shows up as wired device under the router's connected clients"

Comment: @user1686 : https://pastebin.com/gzdZWfJM

Comment: @Ramhound Wdym? Thats what im trying to figure out. The ip of the vm is 10.10.10.19. And yes i have a lenovo laptop, i dont know what that has to do with anything

Comment: @DavidPostill that could be possible, if i restart the router it should be gone?

Comment: @i_Blaze Try it and see :)

Comment: @DavidPostill uh, looks like it worked, thanks lol

Comment: @i_Blaze I've turned my suggestion into an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I have noticed that a device is connected to my LAN connection, and I have no idea what it is

> It has no hostname, its mac address is : F8:75:A4:22:B9:9C, that is a mac address from LCFC (HeFei) Electronics Technology.

From a very similar question at [Solved - How to kick/block a LAN connection? (LCFC (HeFei) Electronics Technolgy) | SmallNetBuilder Forums](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/how-to-kick-block-a-lan-connection-lcfc-hefei-electronics-technolgy.73067/):

> turns out to be a lenovo thinkpad laptop that was disconnected from the router, I hibernated the laptop then unplugged the ethernet cable few hours ago, however it still shows up as wired device under the router's connected clients

So it may well be an old connection that is still showing on the router even though the device is no longer connected via that particular connection.

Restarting your router will refresh it's list of connections (the OP has confirmed that this fixed his particular issue).

Note that restarting all devices is always a good idea when seeing an unusual problem on your network before spending time on additional troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you, you are the nicest person i met on the stack sites!

Answer (score 2):

Its some kind of Lenovo Tech.

My ThinkCentre M720Q has a MAC from: LCFC(HeFei) Electronics Technology co., ltd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).